# No output of a procedure in Oracle 11g when using toad

Tags: oracle11g, toad

[image]I am using oracle 11g and connecting using toad 9.5. My procedure shows that the procedure is successfully created, but when I try to run the procedure it also shows that the procedure is successfully completed, but I don't get any output.

My procedure :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE procPrintHelloWorld
IS
  BEGIN

 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hello World!');

END;
/
```

I run it as:

```
EXEC procPrintHelloWorld;
```

And I get no output...

Comment: What "output" are you looking for?  Does the procedure have `out` parameters?  Is it trying to write to `dbms_output`?  Something else?

Comment: should be AS instead of IS

Answer (score 0):

Execute it in Toad's Editor. View the DBMS Output panel at the bottom. If you don't see it right-click in the Editor and see the Desktop menu flyout. Select DBMS Output. On the DBMS Output panel you need to enable output. Click the button with the red circle. It will go green. Now execute your procedure. Be sure that you are executing and not compiling.

Comment: I see dbms output(disabled) in my toad as i added a picture above

Comment: You need to enable it.